# How to find how many records have a certain picklist value?

Tags: soql, custom-field, picklist, developer, record

I need to delete picklist values for a Region field for the Opportunity object. However, before I delete them, I need to find out if the values are used elsewhere in other Objects, etc. I don't want to delete it if is used elsewhere. However if it is not used anywhere else and also not used on the Opportunity object I will delete it. How do I do this? I have tried some queries such as:

SELECT Region__c FROM Account WHERE Region__c IN ('Great Lakes West')

but have not had any luck. I am not getting an error but no results are being returned, even for ones where I know it is used.

Also, the picklist is not a multipicklist field, therefore INCLUDES does not work for the query.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SOQL to query on a picklist field you only need to set the value to an equals sign, so your query would be

SELECT Region__c FROM Account WHERE Region__c = 'Great Lakes West'

Any records that have that value selected should appear on your report.

In regards to finding objects that have this value as an option, I would recommend downloading the force.com IDE as that will give you a view of all your metadata.  Once you have an IDE you would be able to search your whole org for the value "Great Lakes West" in any picklist.  After finding what picklists have these values, you would be able to search them using a SOQL query.

I don't want this response to be too long, so I'm only going to post a link on how to get started with the force.com IDE, but just a warning, it has a steep learning curve to get started if you have little to no programming experience (not saying that's the case :))

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_install.htm

Answer (score 0):

use WHERE Region__c includes ('Great Lakes West').
The IN operation looks for Ids (typically) in a set of possible values, for example, given a set of Contact Ids 'contactIds', you can find the corresponding names with
SELECT Name FROM Contact where Id in :contactIds

Comment: I tried this and got an error: INVALID_QUERY_FILTER OPERATOR...[object Object]: SELECT Region__c FROM Account WHERE Region__c includes ('Central') ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:37 includes or excludes operator only valid on multipicklist field

Comment: Sorry, I had thought you mean a multi-select picklist.  For a regular picklist, just use "=", @Patrick's Answer is correct